# CSS switch of grid and list view

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a Grid or list view like dropbox viewing of files.
anyone has sample of follow CSS? any help or link will be great for me to start with.
or they are just make with `class="rows"`
and `<div class="row">` for list view 
and `<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1">
</div></div>` 
[image: List View]

[image: GridView]

Comment: _“or they are just make with [...]”_ - use your browser dev tools, and find out …?

Comment: @CBroe they are using their own css files. i will try with bootstrap rows and cols and come back here
mrid i haven tried.i simply just goolging for a understanding before i try. if there isnt any. i will try it first.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp
is it not just using this? and styling it with CSS how you want it?

Comment: yes li is maining for list view. but the tricky is the toggling part which i don't know how they work

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get the elements with class="column"
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

// Declare a loop variable
var i;

// List View
function listView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "100%";
  }
}

// Grid View
function gridView() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = "50%";
  }
}

/* Optional: Add active class to the current button (highlight it) */
var container = document.getElementById("btnContainer");
var btns = container.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <h2>List View or Grid View</h2>

  <p>Click on a button to choose list view or grid view.</p>

  <div id="btnContainer">
    <button class="btn" onclick="listView()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> List</button>
    <button class="btn active" onclick="gridView()"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Grid</button>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Column 4</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```